# DeltaXML Diff like library for .Net?

Tags: .net, xml, merge, diff

We are currently using DeltaXML in our .Net application to analyse two versions of .xml files regarding their differences, but since DeltaXML is a java application/library, we're looking for a more homogeneous way to accomplish that task.

Does anyone know a .Net diff library similiar to DeltaXML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a long time since your post, but DeltaXML does now (June 2011) have a .NET version of DeltaXML Core. There are also .NET versions of the new DeltaXML DocBook Compare and DeltaXML DITA Compare - these are dedicated to the specific DocBook and DITA formats and enable publication of redlined/blacklined documents showing changes.

Comment: Totally forgot about this Q here, but - Robin, yep we will upgrade to their .net version somewhere down the road.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know DeltaXML, but you could try [XML Diff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx) from Microsoft, which is available in source - well at least parts of it.

I have used it successfully for doing "XML aware" diffs on test results.

However, it looks rather old/defunct now, so your milage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Not a library, but an application that computes deltas based on language (e.g., XML) structures.  See [SD Smart Differencer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer).  There is an XML version even if it isn't obvious from the web site.